# How do I implement Google sign-in on iOS app?

Tags: oauth, google-signin

I've been tasked with adding a "Sign In with Google" button to an iOS app. For background, I'm a contract developer doing work for a customer, and I do not own the app in question.

I did a quick search for how to do this, but the only answer I could find involved "set up a project in the Google API console" followed by "add a GIDSignInButton to your layout".

I do not have access to the app owner's Google Developer account (or know if they even have one), and I certainly do not want to "set up a project" in my own Google account that is associated with a customer's app.

Furthermore, the iOS project I'm working with does not currently have any third-party library integrations (no Swift packages, no CocoaPods, no workspace file) and I strongly prefer to keep it this way.

Is it possible to do Google authentication using a standard OAuth process (i.e. open a web page, and handle the redirect after authentication completes)? I have done other OAuth integrations this way so I know how it works.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can sign-in using OAuth without using an SDK. Here are the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app).

You will be required to setup a project and configure it's OAuth settings. This manages how your app will appear to users and implements OAuth security controls. No way around this, so you'll want to work with your Google Cloud administrator to gain access to an existing project or create a new one.